# Using the ScanR API from gouv.fr for a POST request that, given a company name, returns its id

Tags: rest

I'm trying to use the ScanR API:

- Technical documentation: https://scanr-api.enseignementsup-recherche.gouv.fr/api/swagger-ui.html
- General presentation: https://api.gouv.fr/les-api/scanR
- Online interface: https://scanr.enseignementsup-recherche.gouv.fr/

My goal is to **give the API a structure/company name, and receive, among others, a structure/company id**. Then I am able use the GET endpoint '/v2/structures/structure/{id}' to access the description.

I believe that to do this, I would use the **POST endpoint '/v2/structures/search'**.
However, **I don't manage to structure the query** in a way that works.

Can anyone give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

The scanR team kindly provided an example that I share here:

```
url_structures = "https://scanr-api.enseignementsup-recherche.gouv.fr/api/v2/structures/search"
my_query = "carbon\ waters"

params = {
   "pageSize": 12,
   "query": my_query
}

scanr_output = requests.post(url_structures, json=params).json()
```